Migrate a standalone SQLite 3.12.x database with Django configuration
I'm evaluating the use of django for the migration of a SQLite database to Postgres.
The database was not created as a django project, but instead used for other applications.
I'm attempting to configure django to do routine migrations of various development SQLite databases to Postgres.
I continue to fail with regard django creating the json exports from SQLite.
I receive the following error:
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: django_admin_log

I have configured my database in settings.py
I have run:
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py for migration tips etc..

Perhaps I'm missing the preconfiguration steps etc...and looking for help.

Does the django_admin_log table exist in the SQLite database?

No.  The sqlite database knows nothing about django.  It was built prior to trying to use django for anything.

Since you are trying to dump from SQLite database you need make sure that all the tables are exist. The django_admin_log doesn't exist so it preventing you to dump data.  You can also try to exlude the table which giving you the errors dumpdata yourApp --exclude=django_admin_log 

First Dump data:
python manage.py dumpdata --database online_database <other parameters> > fixture.json

if needed exclude auth.permission exclude contenttypes
python manage.py dumpdata --database online_database --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > fixture.json

now Load data
python manage.py loaddata --database local_database <other parameters> path/to/your/fixtures/fixture.json


exact same error with all 3 commands, updating the online_database to the value I have of default  from DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'MyDatabaseName.db',
},
}
